# SKYPE install deleted folders

Tags: skype

I removed folders accidently from skype manually, now if im trying to install by sudo apt-get install skype it is actually installing but I dont have an icon to run it any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just reinstalling the package.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge skype`

`sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: Tried already and didnt work